# Why do I manually need to add !package.json in .gcloudignore when setting **/package.json in .gitignore

Tags: git, gcloud, gitignore, google-cloud-build, gcloudignore

I would like both git and gcloud to ignore all `package.json` files except the one in the base folder. I've set `**/package.json` in the .gitignore file which works fine except that gcloud also ignores the `package.json` in the base directory.

I have solved this by creating a `.gcloudignore` file with the content:

```
.git
.gitignore

#!include:.gitignore
!package.json
```

As I want exactly the same behaviour from gcloud and git I would have expected to be able to only set the `.gitignore` file. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `.gcloudignore` is needed to ignore files/directory is that it is the only required file if you want to ignore files when you deploy **inside** the gcloud environment. Basically these files have similar functions, `.gcloudignore` only works within the gcloud environment.

The syntax below should be used inside `.gcloudignore` so that it will exclude all the files or directory inside your `.gitignore` file those files/directory:

```
#!include:.gitignore
```

You may check this documentation on [`.gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore?hl=en) for additional information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand how your answer is supposed to address my issue... What are the concrete steps you suggest I take and what is the rational behind them?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please do check.

Comment: Hi thanks for the clarification. A) When I don't put a .gcloudignore file it just uses the standard one which treats **/package.json in the unexpected way I mentioned. B) Also with the .gcloudignore it treats the **/package.json in a way which I would not expect. Why is that happening?